# How can i fix a "System.Security.SecurityException" within an Azure web application?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've uploaded my web app onto azure and get the following error when i try to run it:

> The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique. Inaccessible logs: Security.

The code does write event logs and it works on local machines cause you can run it as an administrator.

How am i able to work around this in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Applications can write to the application event log but they do not have access to the SECURITY logs due to the sandbox . Any event logs written to application event log are visible in event log.xml....

More details in https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox